# Need help, I want to pass a parameter to dependent component

Tags: c#, autofac

> I think this problem does not duplicate [Autofac: Resolving dependencies with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327177/autofac-resolving-dependencies-with-parameters). Please read purpose section below.

I declared a `IContentProvider` and a implementation named `WebContentProvider` with a `url` as constructor parameter.

```
interface IContentProvider
{
    string Content { get; }
}

class WebContentProvider {
    public WebContentProvider(string url) { ... }
    public string Content => GetHtmlFrom(this.url);
}
```

Now, there are two consumer class need WebContentProvder to provide content from different url. They all implement interface `IContentUser`.

```
class FirstContentUser : IContentUser
{
    IContentProvider provider;

    public FirstContentUser(IContentProvider provider)
    {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public void Use()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[First Content User]");
        Console.WriteLine(provider.Content);
    }
}
```

class `SecondContentUser` is similar.

Here is my registration code:

```
public AttempAutofac()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<WebContentProvider>()
        .As<IContentProvider>();
        // HERE!!! how can I use `url` metadata given below,
        // or some other way to get the url while resolving

    builder.RegisterType<FirstContentUser>()
        .As<IContentUser>()
        .WithMetadata("url", "http://the.1st.url");

    builder.RegisterType<SecondContentUser>()
        .As<IContentUser>()
        .WithMetadata("url", "http://the.2nd.url");

    container = builder.Build();
}
```

Later, I want to use `scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<IContentUser>>()` to get all consumer instances.

I hope in the near future, a new class `FasterWebContentProvider` can be configured to instead of `WebContentProvider` easily, just by changing one registration line.

Here is my purpose:

1. Autofac is used to compose implementations according to interfaces. I want everything is decided in registration, not in resolving stage. That means the consumer supply a resource location, then Autofac choose a `IContentProvider` implementation to load the content(resource) from the location, and provide the content to the specific consumer.
2. All interface and implementations are pre-defined so I cannot modify them (cannot use "the `Func implicit relationship" way).
3. The parameters for resolving `IContentProvider` are dynamic, come from different consumes, not only a config value. So I cannot use "lambda expression registrations" way which is mentioned in that answer.
4. Maybe Autofac modules can resolve the problem, but I have not idea how to do that.

I don't know clearly if I have designed correctly. I will appreciate someone who can point how to improve the design.

Comment: As a side note, if you are manually calling scope.Resolve at some point in your code you've fallen into the service locator anti-pattern trap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autofac: Resolving dependencies with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327177/autofac-resolving-dependencies-with-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pondered over this problem then figure out one thing:

The instances of `IContentProvider` should be created without their consumers, so they cannot get any information from a consumer. Thus I must register different `IContentProvider` instances or creators then a consumer can find one by key or name.

Following ['How do I pick a service implementation by context?'](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html), I got a solution:

```
private void Register()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.Register(c => new WebContentProvider("http://the.1st.url"))
        .Keyed<IContentProvider>(typeof(FirstContentUser));

    builder.Register(c => new WebContentProvider("http://the.2nd.url"))
        .Keyed<IContentProvider>(typeof(SecondContentUser));

    builder.RegisterType<FirstContentUser>()
            .As<IContentUser>()
            .WithParameter(
            CreateResolvedParameter<IContentProvider, FirstContentUser>());

    builder.RegisterType<SecondContentUser>()
        .As<IContentUser>()
            .WithParameter(
            CreateResolvedParameter<IContentProvider, SecondContentUser>());

    container = builder.Build();
}

private static ResolvedParameter CreateResolvedParameter<ParamType, KeyType>()
{
    return new ResolvedParameter(
        (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(ParamType),
        (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveKeyed<ParamType>(typeof(KeyType)));
}
```